# latexmk : Clean multiple files created by custom dependency

Tags: latexmk

I am using `latexmk` with a custom dependency that is used to create `.tex` files from `.svg` files.

The problem that arises is, that the conversion actually creates two files, the `.tex` file and a `.pdf` file that is included in the `.tex` file.

From my understanding of `latexmk` it is not aware of the existence of the additional `.pdf` files and thus does not remove them during a cleanup.

I tried circumventing this problem by giving the extra files generated a special extension `.gen.pdf` and

- (a) adding this extension to the list of generated extensions using `push @generated_exts, "gen.pdf";` or
- (b) adding this extension to the list of extra extensions to remove in a cleanup `$clean_ext = "gen.pdf";`

but neither of these worked.

Is there any way make `latexmk` aware of these files so that they can be removed during cleanup?

Comment: Could you send me a very simple test case (to my address in the `latexmk` documentation), with both the source files and the definition of your custom dependency.  I see a possibility for a simple solution, but I would like to test it before posting it.

Comment: @JohnCollins I just emailed you the minimal example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution for defining the custom dependency.  It contains a one-line addition to the OP's code:

```
$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1; 
$cleanup_includes_generated = 1;

add_cus_dep('gnplt', 'tex', 0, 'gnplt2tex');
sub gnplt2tex {
   $abs_path = File::Spec->rel2abs( $_[0] );
   rdb_add_generated( "$_[0].tex", "$_[0].gen.pdf" );
   ($vol, $dir, $fname) = File::Spec->splitpath($abs_path);
   system( "cd $dir && " .
    "gnuplot -e \"set output \'$fname.gen.tex\'\" \"$fname.gnplt\"" );
   system( "mv \"$abs_path.gen.tex\" \"$abs_path.tex\"" );
   system( "epstopdf \"$abs_path.gen.eps\" && rm \"$abs_path.gen.eps\"" );
}
```

The critical parts are

1. Setting `$cleanup_includes_generated = 1`, which the OP had already done. This ensures that a clean up deletes files in a list of generated files that is held internally by `latexmk`.
2. Using (the not-currently documented) `rdb_add_generated` subroutine to add a specific file to the list of generated files.  This is my only change to the OP's code.

The setting of `$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1` is actually unnecessary in the current version of `latexmk`, but that could change in the future.

**Warnings**:

1. The use of `$cleanup_includes_generated = 1` is potentially a little dangerous, since it also implies that a cleanup also includes deletion of all the files that `latexmk` finds in `\openout` lines in the .log file from latex runs and also any found from `OUTPUT` lines in the .fls file.  This is a slight potential for mis-parsed lines etc.  But you can see from the relevant lines in the .fdb_latexmk file that the detection of generated files is normally reliable.
2. With the current version (4.55e) of `latexmk`, the use of `$cleanup_includes_generated = 1` implies that a cleanup using `-c` option of `latexmk` deletes some files that should be preserved, i.e., the .dvi file generated by `latex` or the .pdf file generated by `pdflatex` (etc).  This doesn't matter for the `-C` option, which is documented to cause deletion of these files.

Comment: As I already wrote in my mails: Thank you very much, John, for your quick and perfect help!