# Cleaning intermediate files from custom latexmk dependencies without deleting the final PDF

Tags: latexmk

I am using latexmk to compile my document, and have written a custom dependency rule to generate some files to include. The processing involves creating some intermediate files which I'd like to clean with `-c`. However, these intermediate files are only removed if I set `$cleanup_includes_generated = 1;` which results in the output PDF being deleted also.

For a minimal working example, use the following `latexmkrc` file which simply copies a file to an intermediate and then final destination. It uses the `rdb_add_generated()` routine mentioned by John Collins in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423249/7432) about cleaning custom dependencies.

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1;

add_cus_dep('txt', 'inc', 0, 'test_dep');
sub test_dep {
    system("cp $_[0].txt $_[0].tmp");
    system("cp $_[0].tmp $_[0].inc");
    rdb_add_generated("$_[0].tmp");
}
```

Use a simple TeX document `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \input{message.inc}
\end{document}
```

And an even simpler file `message.txt` to process:

```
Hello world!
```

Running `latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode` creates a file database `main.fdb_latexmk` which includes the `message.tmp` intermediate file. However, `latexmk -c` and `latexmk -C` only remove the `message.inc` file and leave the intermediate one.

Changing `$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1;` to `$cleanup_includes_generated = 1;` in the latexmk config results in the intermediate file being deleted. However, this results in `latexmk -c` behaving the same as `latexmk -C` and removing the output PDF, which is not ideal.

I suspect `rdb_add_generated()` is adding the intermediate file to the general list of generated files rather than a list of files generated by custom dependencies. Is there some way to mark it as a custom generated file, or am I stuck with choosing between leaving the intermediate files uncleaned or deleting all generated files?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but personally I would do something like this using `make`, and call `latexmk` from `make` to do the things that `make` *can't* do - in particular, automatically re-running LaTeX enough times for cross references etc to stabilize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is actually due to a couple of bugs in `latexmk`.  (a) If you specify `$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1;`, then `latexmk` fails to delete the extra generated file that you specified.  (b) If you specify `$cleanup_includes_generated = 1;`, then `latexmk` deletes files that it shouldn't (e.g., a `.pdf` file) when you use `latexmk -c`.

I've corrected this for the next release of `latexmk`.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify (b), did you mean `$cleanup_includes_generated = 1;`? With `$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1;` latexmk leaves the PDF for me.

Comment: Yes.  I've corrected the answer.